# NodeJs: How to use a Promise across multiple files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I originally had a file that had a promise on it which worked perfectly fine, but then i realized that I will be reusing these functions a lot, so decided to create a new file to hold the function and use module.export so that I could have access to it every where. If I console.log crop_inventory in the new file(GlobalResource.js), I get 1000 which is correct, but when I try to access the data in my original file, I get 0.

```
homeController.js

var ResourceGlobal = require('../global/globalResources/ResourcesGlobal');

app.get('/game/:gameid/home', function(req,res){
    if(global.gameId == req.params.gameid){
        setResourceInventory().then(function(){
            console.log(ResourceGlobal.crop_inventory)//I get 0, here even though it should be 1000
            res.render('GameEngine/home/gameHome');
        });
    } else{
        res.send(500, "Not authorized to view this page.");
    }
});


function setResourceInventory(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        Promise.all([ResourceGlobal.getCrop(), ResourceGlobal.getLumber(), ResourceGlobal.getOre(), ResourceGlobal.getOil()]).then(function(){
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

ResourceGlobal.js

```
var db = require('../../../../db');


module.exports = {

//Resources
crop_inventory: 0,
lumber_inventory: 0,
ore_inventory: 0,
oil_inventory: 0,

//Function gets crop inventory and sets global variable
getCrop: function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let sql = "SELECT Crop_Inventory FROM resources WHERE resources_FK_PlayerId = (?) AND resources_FK_GameId = (?)";
        var value = [global.id, global.gameId];
        db.query(sql, value, function(err,result,fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else{
                crop_inventory = result[0].Crop_Inventory;
                console.log(crop_inventory) //I get 1000 which is correct
                resolve();
            }
        });
    })
}
```

}

//3 more function goes for lumber, ore and oil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) you need to pass the value that you want to be resolved. Also, you should `reject` the promise in case of error. So, in your case `getCrop()` should be:

```
getCrop: function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let sql = "SELECT Crop_Inventory FROM resources WHERE resources_FK_PlayerId = (?) AND resources_FK_GameId = (?)";
        var value = [global.id, global.gameId];
        db.query(sql, value, function(err,result,fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            } else{
                crop_inventory = result[0].Crop_Inventory;
                console.log(crop_inventory) //I get 1000 which is correct
                resolve(crop_inventory);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Now [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) would be resolved when all the promises inside it are resolved. And it resolves to an array which contains the resolved values of each promise in the same order. Hence, `setResourceInventory()` should be:

```
function setResourceInventory(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        Promise.all([ResourceGlobal.getCrop(), ResourceGlobal.getLumber(), ResourceGlobal.getOre(), ResourceGlobal.getOil()]).then(function(data){
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

So now you can access the data as:

```
setResourceInventory().then(function(data){
    console.log(data[0]); //getCrop value
    console.log(data[1]); //getLumber value
    res.render('GameEngine/home/gameHome');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference your `setResourceInventory()` function can be simplified:

```
function setResourceInventory(){
        return Promise.all([ResourceGlobal.getCrop(), ResourceGlobal.getLumber(), ResourceGlobal.getOre(), ResourceGlobal.getOil()])
}
```

`Promise.all()` returns a promise which is thenable.